# how to replace $ value in a file using sed command?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am using below command to replace some values in a file. But its not get replaced even though the command is running fine.

```
sed -i 's|"TIBEMS:U1278:${Internal.Agent Name}"|"TIBEMS:U1278:${External.Agent Name}"|g' EMS_PRIMS01_7111_Monitor.hrb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the meta-characters

```
 sed -i "s|\"TIBEMS:U1278:\${Internal.Agent Name}\"|\"TIBEMS:U1278:\${External.Agent Name}\"|g" EMS_PRIMS01_7111_Monitor.hrb 
 #      ^^             ^^                     ^^ ^^               ^^                       ^^
 #  Notice the escaping done for all the meta-characters i.e. '"' and '$'
```

With this your in-place replacement will work.

Comment: still it not get replaced

Comment: @Ricky Which `sed` version are you in? i.e. output of `sed --version`? and can you provide a snippet of your file `EMS_PRIMS01_7111_Monitor.hrb`

Comment: its worked after i modified it like **sed -i 's|TIBEMS:U1278:\${Internal.Agent Name}|TIBEMS:U1278:${External.Agent Name}|g' EMS_PRIMS01_7111_Monitor.hrb.Thanks for your help :)